# What happened my ttyS0 has no irq list in /proc/interrupt

Tags: linux, serial-port, kernel, driver, uart

In this system, it blocks(hang) in the following cases:

```
echo "test" > /dev/ttyS0

cat /dev/ttyS0 #read nothing even scope show the UART data there 

stty -F /dev/ttyS0 115200
```

If I set serial console in grub, the Linux (CentOS7, Ubuntu18, Redhat7...) can't boot into shell. ( even no getty yet )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are not using it.

update grub to use serial console

or try:

cat /dev/ttyS0

then you will see it on the list.

For block issue, check you see interrupt on it or not.
If no, some problem there.